# The first and the last date that a variable appear in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, datetime

I want to have the first and the last date that a variable appear in my dataframe :

```py
   datetime           A
2019-03-04 00:03      1
2019-03-04 00:04      1
2019-03-04 00:05      2
2019-03-04 00:06      2 
2019-03-04 00:07      1
2019-03-04 00:08      2
2019-03-04 00:09      3
2019-03-04 00:10      3
2019-03-04 00:11      3
2019-03-04 00:12      4
2019-03-04 00:13      3
```

desired output :

```py
A            First                     Last
1      2019-03-04 00:03          2019-03-04 00:07
2      2019-03-04 00:05          2019-03-04 00:08
3      2019-03-04 00:09          2019-03-04 00:13
4      2019-03-04 00:12          2019-03-04 00:12
```

I tried this :

```py
data_df=pd.Series({x : y.datetime.tolist() for x , y in df.groupby('A')})
data_df=pd.DataFrame({'A':data_df.index, 'datetime':data_df.values})
data_df
```

I have this output

```py
A                              datetime
1       [2019-03-04 00:03,2019-03-04 00:04,2019-03-04 00:07]
2       [2019-03-04 00:05,2019-03-04 00:06,2019-03-04 00:08]
3       [2019-03-04 00:09,2019-03-04 00:10,2019-03-04 00:11,2019-03-04 00:13]
4       [2019-03-04 00:12]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `agg` and pass a list of funcs on your `groupby` object:

```
In[108]:
df.groupby('A').agg(['first','last'])

Out[108]: 
             datetime                    
                first                last
A                                        
1 2019-03-04 00:03:00 2019-03-04 00:07:00
2 2019-03-04 00:05:00 2019-03-04 00:08:00
3 2019-03-04 00:09:00 2019-03-04 00:13:00
4 2019-03-04 00:12:00 2019-03-04 00:12:00
```

If required you can call `reset_index`:

```
In[109]:
df.groupby('A').agg(['first','last']).reset_index()

Out[109]: 
   A            datetime                    
                   first                last
0  1 2019-03-04 00:03:00 2019-03-04 00:07:00
1  2 2019-03-04 00:05:00 2019-03-04 00:08:00
2  3 2019-03-04 00:09:00 2019-03-04 00:13:00
3  4 2019-03-04 00:12:00 2019-03-04 00:12:00
```

This calls [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last) for each group

**Update**
Thanks to @Wen-Ben for the suggestion, if we select the single column then this doesn't create a multi-index in the df:

```
In[110]:
df.groupby('A')['datetime'].agg(['first','last'])

Out[110]: 
                first                last
A                                        
1 2019-03-04 00:03:00 2019-03-04 00:07:00
2 2019-03-04 00:05:00 2019-03-04 00:08:00
3 2019-03-04 00:09:00 2019-03-04 00:13:00
4 2019-03-04 00:12:00 2019-03-04 00:12:00
```

Which matches your desired output

Comment: df.groupby('A')['datetime'].agg(['first','last'])

Comment: @Wen-Ben I guess that matches what the OP has actually asked for, I will update and thanks